# Hibernate: How to map ManyToOne inside a single class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have the following situation.
An employee can have a manager, but the manager is an employeee to.

ERM:
Employee n < has > 1 manager

Explanation: One or more employees can have one or no manager manager. How to map this inside an single POJO?
When google about it, I found only a two class based solution like this one
http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-manytoone-hibernate

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private Integer employeeId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employeeId", nullable=true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Employee managerId;

    /* Getter and setter */
}
```

Setting managerId

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
/* bla bla bla */
emp.setManagerId(emp);
```

I don't see managerId inside my table... 
I'm using

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Comment: Why did you mark the join column as `insertable = false, updatable = false`? Also, please rename the field `managerId` to `manager`. Finally, isn't it a bit strange, in your example code, that the employee is his own manager?

Answer (score 2):

`Employee <-> Manager` relationship is a sample of an entity having a self-referencing relationship.

An employee will have a reference to its manager - this will be mapped as `@ManyToOne`. This will be the owning side of the relationship where we can define a `@JoinColumn`.

A manager will have a collection of its subordinates - this will be mapped as `@OneToMany`. This will be the inverse side of the relationship and will specify the `mappedBy` attribute.

Here's the sample code of the Employee entity having self-referencing relationship (bi-directional).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGER_ID")
    private Employee manager;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
    private List<Employee> subordinates = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    // Getters and Setters
...
}
```

Here's sample code on persisting manager and its employees:

```
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Employee manager = new Employee();
    manager.setName("John");

    Employee emp1 = new Employee();
    emp1.setName("James");

    Employee emp2 = new Employee();
    emp2.setName("Anna");

    // define both sides of the relationship
    emp1.setManager(manager);
    emp2.setManager(manager);
    manager.getSubordinates().add(emp1);
    manager.getSubordinates().add(emp2);

    em.persist(manager);
    em.persist(emp1);
    em.persist(emp2);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Here's how the schema was generated by Hibernate/JPA:

```
Hibernate: 
    create table EMPLOYEE (
        id bigint not null auto_increment,
        name varchar(255),
        MANAGER_ID bigint,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    alter table EMPLOYEE 
        add constraint FK_slgfbmxe6gqdcw80b5gvn16ye 
        foreign key (MANAGER_ID) 
        references EMPLOYEE (id)
```

Sample of this implementation is available in my Git [repo](https://github.com/balagueri21/sample-codes/tree/master/SelfReferencingEntity).

Answer (score 0):

Both your field reference in fact the same column - employeeId. Change

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="employeeId", nullable=true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Employee managerId;
```

to

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="managerId", nullable=true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Employee manager;
```

Then after creation you will see managerId column in the table

Comment: Maybe add references as well?